# Finding the max value of a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the maximum value of the following expression?
$$\cos^2\left(\frac\pi4 + x\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac\pi4 - x\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, we know that $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x),$ so $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-x).$
It follows that your expression becomes $2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)$ and the maximum value of this function is $2$.

Comment: Did you perhaps omit an exponent?  (Otherwise, this is probably the approach the poser of the problem was looking for.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Ah yes, thank you for noting my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar approach with @juantheron, but here I use sum-to-product angle formula.

Given

$$2\sin\alpha \cos \alpha=\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}+ \sin{(\alpha-\beta)}$$

$$2\cos\alpha \sin \alpha=\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}- \sin{(\alpha-\beta)}$$

The provided expression is equivalent to: 
\begin{align} 
1-\sin^2{(x+\frac{\pi}4)} +\sin^2{(x-\frac{\pi}4)}&=1-[ \sin{(x+\frac{\pi}4)} -\sin{(x-\frac{\pi}4)}] [ \sin{(x+\frac{\pi}4)} +\sin{(x-\frac{\pi}4)}]\\&=1-(2\sin x \cos \frac{\pi}4) (2\cos x \sin\frac{\pi}4)\\&=1-\sin 2x \sin  \frac{\pi}2\\ &= 1-\sin 2x
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using $$\bullet\; \sin (A+B) = \sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$

and $$\bullet\; \ \cos (A+B) = \cos A\cos B-\sin A \sin B$$

$$\displaystyle \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right) = \left[\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]^2$$ and $$\displaystyle \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right) = \left[\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]^2$$

Now let  $$\displaystyle y = \displaystyle \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)+\displaystyle \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right) = \left[\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]^2+\left[\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]^2$$

So we get $$\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{2}(\cos x-\sin x)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\sin x-\cos x)^2 = \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x-2\sin x\cdot \cos x$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$$ and using $$\; \bullet 2\sin x\cdot \cos x=\sin 2x$$

So we get $$y=1-\sin 2x$$

Now we know that $\displaystyle\bullet\;  -1\leq \sin 2x\leq 1$

So we get $$\large\bf{y_{max.} = 1-(-1) = 2}$$ and $$\large\bf{y_{min.} = 1-1 =0}$$

Comment: Or we could just use $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2x$. I think it would be shorter.

Comment: Yes Gummy bears ...

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 \cos^2\left(\frac\pi4 + x\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac\pi4 - x\right)
 &= 1+\cos^2\left(\frac\pi4 + x\right)-\cos^2\left(\frac\pi4 - x\right)\\
 &= 1+\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4 + x\right)+\cos\left(\frac\pi4 - x\right)\right)
    \left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4 + x\right)-\cos\left(\frac\pi4 - x\right)\right)\\
 &= 1-4\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\sin(x)\\
 &= 1-2\cos(x)\sin(x)\\
 &= 1 - \sin(2x)
\end{align}

So max value is $1 - (-1) = 2$
and min value is $1-1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The general method is to use calculus and differentiate and set the resulting expression equal to zero to find the stationary points (max/min). However, as users have given a shorter approach you may favour their answers. I like to give general approaches.